# Incompatible plugins for android-apt after upgrading to Android Studio 2.3

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-apt

After upgrading from 2.2 to 2.3 I see this warning

[image]

and when I try to compile the project I see this compilation error

[image]

How can i solve this issue without downgrading to a previous gradle version? 
Is there any update of android-apt that can solve this issue?

Answer (score 181, accepted):

The `android-apt` plugin **has been deprecated**.
Check here for the [migration guide](https://github.com/littlerobots/android-apt):

> As of the Android Gradle plugin version 2.2, all functionality that was previously provided by android-apt is now available in the Android plugin.

You can remove `android-apt` by following the migration guide to get the equivalent functionalities.

The important parts from the **migration guide**:

> - Make sure you are on the Android Gradle 2.2 plugin or newer.
> - Remove the `android-apt` plugin from your build scripts
> - Change all `apt`, `androidTestApt` and `testApt` dependencies to their new format:

```
dependencies {
   compile 'com.google.dagger:dagger:2.0'
   annotationProcessor 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.0'
}
```

Also in the Android Gradle plugin there is an explicit check for this, which is what you are seeing:

> using incompatible plugins for the annotation processing android-apt

**Future Android Gradle plugin versions will not be compatible** with the way `android-apt` works, which is the reason for that check.

Comment: And in the Android Gradle plugin Google has an explicit check for it, which is what you are seeing. Future Android Gradle versions will not be compatible with the way `android-apt` works, which is the reason for that check.

Comment: where is the check?

Comment: I don't have any apt's but still get this warning. EDIT: Turns out it was realm

Comment: I didn't see NDROID-pt in my code anywhere, but getting error. What might be the issue?

Comment: I am having this same issue as well. Even I am not using any of things that belong to apt. but @Mubashar as he said I commented apply plug in for realm this worked for me. Now the code is compiling.but is that heppening. Can't we use realm?

Answer (score 49):

For me, I was having this error while using Contentful's **`Vault`** library which specifies that you include:

```
apply plugin: 'com.neenbedankt.android-apt'
```

and

```
compile 'com.contentful.vault:core:2.1.0'
apt 'com.contentful.vault:compiler:2.1.0'
```

What you need to do is **DELETE** `apply plugin: 'com.neenbedankt.android-apt'`

and then **CHANGE**:

```
compile 'com.contentful.vault:core:2.1.0'
apt 'com.contentful.vault:compiler:2.1.0'
```

to

```
annotationProcessor 'com.contentful.vault:compiler:2.1.0'
annotationProcessor 'com.contentful.vault:core:3.0.1'
```

You can always check https://github.com/contentful/vault for the latest versions

Answer (score 15):

1. Remove apt plugin
2. Change:

   apt -> compile

   testApt -> testAnnotationProcessor

   androidTestApt -> androidTestAnnotationProcessor
3. In your build.gradle (app), add to defaultConfig:

vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true

Answer (score 6):

Piggybacking on @Gabriele Mariotti here since his answer is pretty spot on and implies this but doesn't state it. Gradle also does not suggest this as a valid option though it is as well. The testing equivalent for `androidTestApt` and `testApt` is `androidTestAnnotationProcessor` and `testAnnotationProcessor`.

Example:

```
testApt "com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:$daggerVersion"
androidTestApt "com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:$daggerVersion"
```

Should be changed to

```
testAnnotationProcessor "com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:$daggerVersion"
androidTestAnnotationProcessor "com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:$daggerVersion"
```

Answer (score 1):

In case the annotation processor has arguments, one also might have to change this:

```
apt {
    arguments {
        KEY "VALUE"
    }
}
```

to this:

```
android {
    ...
    defaultConfig {
        ...
        javaCompileOptions {
            annotationProcessorOptions {
                arguments = ['KEY': 'VALUE']
            }
        }
    }
}
```