# Android gradle build issue

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

**strong text**I getting the below error, even though I removed "apt" from the gradle files.

> android-apt plugin is incompatible with the Android Gradle plugin. 
>   Please use 'annotationProcessor' configuration instead.

Currently using `gradle 3.1.0`

Comment: Share your app/gadle code and look into this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47442124/android-studio-3-0-error-android-apt-is-incompatible

Comment: Take a look here: https://bitbucket.org/hvisser/android-apt/wiki/Migration

Comment: Please share your gradle here so after that we get your problem. and refer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47290290/android-studio-3-1-canary-3-gradle-sync-failed