# Error:android-apt plugin is incompatible with the Android Gradle plugin. Please use 'annotationProcessor'

Tags: android

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
```

apply plugin: 'realm-android'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion '26.0.2'

```
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.kolhapur.news"
    minSdkVersion 14
    targetSdkVersion 24
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
```

}

/* IMPORTANT :
 * Be careful when update dependencies, different version library may caused error */
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    // google library
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:24.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:24.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:24.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:24.1.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:9.2.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:9.2.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:9.2.1'

```
// library for api
compile('com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.0.0-beta4') {
    exclude module: 'okhttp'
}**strong text**
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.2.0'
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.0.1'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.1.0'
compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'

// ripple effect library
compile 'com.balysv:material-ripple:1.0.2'
```

}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

Answer (score 0):

Remove these lines

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

And

```
apply plugin: 'com.neenbedankt.android-apt'
```

This works with me.

Answer (score -1):

From this answer [Incompatible plugins for android-apt after upgrading to Android Studio 2.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42574803/incompatible-plugins-for-android-apt-after-upgrading-to-android-studio-2-3?answertab=votes#tab-top)

The `android-apt` plugin **has been deprecated**.
Check here for the [migration guide](https://bitbucket.org/hvisser/android-apt/wiki/Migration):

> As of the Android Gradle plugin version 2.2, all functionality that was previously provided by android-apt is now available in the Android plugin.

You can remove `android-apt` by following the migration guide to get the equivalent functionalities.

The important parts from the **migration guide**:

> - Make sure you are on the Android Gradle 2.2 plugin or newer.
> - Remove the `android-apt` plugin from your build scripts
> - Change all `apt`, `androidTestApt` and `testApt` dependencies to their new format:

```
dependencies {
   compile 'com.google.dagger:dagger:2.0'
   annotationProcessor 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.0'
}
```

Also in the Android Gradle plugin there is an explicit check for this, which is what you are seeing:

> using incompatible plugins for the annotation processing android-apt

**Future Android Gradle plugin versions will not be compatible** with the way `android-apt` works, which is the reason for that check.