# Migrate an old project to Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, build.gradle

I am new to Android Studio. 
need to Migrate an old project to Android Studio

First I got this error :

> android-apt plugin is incompatible with the Android Gradle plugin.  Please use 'annotationProcessor'..
>   Configuration 'compile' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'implementation' and 'api'.
>   It will be removed at the end of 2018. For more information ...

[image]

Then when I make the changes and replace what i need to i get this error:

> 'keyboard|screenSize|orientation|' is incompatible with ...

[image]
anyone having idea about this please help

Comment: How about creating a new project in Android Studio and copy-pasting old project code into the new project?

Comment: Could you include the code of your gradle file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the `android-apt` error refer:

[Incompatible plugins for android-apt after upgrading to Android Studio 2.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42574803/incompatible-plugins-for-android-apt-after-upgrading-to-android-studio-2-3)

Also, in your app gradle file, under dependencies section, change `compile` to `implementation`. (compile will be deprecated at the end of 2018, you should use implementation instead).

For the second one, it seems like (according to the image) that you have an extra `|` at the end (`keyboard|screenSize|orientation|`) try to remove it.

Next time please attach the code itself, it will be much easier to find what's wrong.