# How to resolve this ERROR: android-apt plugin is incompatible with the Android Gradle plugin

Tags: android, build.gradle, android-9.0-pie, retrolambda

After updating `buildToolsVersion 25.0.3 to 28.0.3` and `build:gradle:2.3.3 to 3.4.0` i have facing with these issue; how to resolve these issues thanks

1. ERROR: **android-apt** plugin is incompatible with the Android Gradle
   plugin
2. WARNING: One of the plugins you are using supports Java 8 language
   features. To try the support built into the Android plugin, remove
   the following from your build.gradle:
       apply plugin: **'me.tatarka.retrolambda'**
3. WARNING: API `'variantOutput.getProcessResources()'` is obsolete and has been replaced with `'variantOutput.getProcessResourcesProvider()'`.
   It will be removed at the end of 2019.

Here is my Code **Bulid.gradle** (module: App)

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'android-apt'
apply plugin: 'me.tatarka.retrolambda'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    buildToolsVersion '28.0.3'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.admin.schoolapp"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }


    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            shrinkResources true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }

        debug {
            minifyEnabled true
            shrinkResources true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}

apt {
    arguments {
        androidManifestFile variant.outputs[0].processResources.manifestFile
        resourcePackageName android.defaultConfig.applicationId
    }
}

dependencies {
    //noinspection GradleDependency
    annotationProcessor  'org.androidannotations:androidannotations:4.6.0'
    //noinspection GradleDependency
    implementation 'org.androidannotations:androidannotations-api:4.6.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup:otto:1.3.8'
    implementation 'com.astuetz:pagerslidingtabstrip:1.0.1'
    implementation 'org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.9'
    implementation 'commons-io:commons-io:2.4'
    implementation 'com.koushikdutta.ion:ion:2.2.1'
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.5'
}
```

**Bulid.gradle** (Project: TestProject)

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
        google()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.0'
        classpath 'com.neenbedankt.gradle.plugins:android-apt:1.8'
        classpath 'me.tatarka:gradle-retrolambda:3.7.1'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    mavenCentral()
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Comment: Is it because of some of your dependencies (libraries)?

Comment: yes but to how to resolve i try i lot but issue in apt, and retrolambda

Comment: Maybe try to update the version of your dependencies to the newest? I had a similar issue when my toolkit is actually lower (in lower version) than one of my dependencies.

Comment: i updated all of these. but apt and retrolambda is deprecated thats why.

Comment: for retrolambda i use this https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support#migrate working fine  but other issues are still not resolved.

Comment: Try to add this inside android {
lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
    }
}

Comment: Does this help?: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42574803/incompatible-plugins-for-android-apt-after-upgrading-to-android-studio-2-3

Comment: i already tried this also